# Will making HTTP cookies unique to a given website make cookies aligned with the strictest privacy guidelines?

Tags: cookies

As far as I know, the only privacy problem with cookies is that in general, the owners of website Y could read what a visitor has searched for or had done in website X.

Will making HTTP cookies unique to a given website (so other websites won't be able to access it) make cookies aligned with the strictest privacy guidelines (or will there still be a privacy and maybe also information security problem)?

Answer (score 1):

> owners of website Y could read what a visitor has searched for or had done in website X.

No, it's not. A cookie set by `www.example.com` cannot be read by `www.another-example.com`. That's a fundamental property of cookies: they are tied to a domain. Some are even tied to a subdomain, making a cookie from `one.example.com` being unable to be read from `two.example.com`.

What happens is that lots of sites will use some ad network to display ads. And those ad networks (for example, `adnet.net`) will receive a request with a special header: `Referer`, and that header says you are coming from `example.com`. And `adnet.net` can set a cookie giving you an unique ID.

So if you access `example.com`, and they use `adnet.net` as their ad-provider, your unique ID for `adnet.net` is sent to `adnet.net` and the `Referer` header says it's coming from example.com. They will record on their database that you accessed `example.com`, `another-example.com` and any other site you accessed and happened to have ads from `adnet.net`.

No cookie from `adnet.net` can be read either by `example.com` nor `another-example.com`, but `adnet.net` knows for sure you accessed both of them. And not only ads. A lot of sites are built using JQuery, and to not have to host `jquery.js` they just use a CDN and link that file directly. And the CDN too receives a request with `Referer` header, and the CDN can set a special cookie with an unique ID on it.

> Will making HTTP cookies unique to a given website (so other websites won't be able to access it) make cookies aligned with the strictest privacy guidelines (or will there still be a privacy and maybe also information security problem)?

It won't make any difference, because your cookies cannot be read by anyone else. What you can do is to now have any external resources (so host all your images, all scripts, all ads). This way nobody can know your users by cross-referencing ad network and CND cookies.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I know, the only privacy problem with cookies is that in general, the owners of website Y could read what a visitor has searched for or had done in website X.

The privacy problem with cookies is that they can be used to track a user over multiple sites and specific web pages. And based on these information a profile can be created about the interests of the user - which allow targeted ads and similar.

> ... so other websites won't be able to access it

In general other websites cannot access the cookies from another website, i.e. facebook.com cannot access cookies from example.com. The problems are the cookies these web sites itself set, i.e. cookies from Facebook when a like button is included in any page, cookies from Google if Google Analytics is used in a page etc.

For example a `<img src=https://facebook.com/thumbsup.gif>` on the site `example.com` will traditionally<sup>1</sup> result in `facebook.com` being able to set a cookie for the domain `facebook.com` and if a similar fragment is include in `whatever.example.org` then Facebook will see the previously set cookie and is thus able to detect the same user over multiple sites and pages. Facebook cannot access the cookies for `example.com` or `whatever.example.org` though, only their own.

This also means that your approach of unique cookies will not help, since it does not addresses the actual problem.

---

<sup>1</sup> Using so called third-party cookies this way gets more and more prevented by browsers to provide better privacy for the users, so these simple tracking techniques cease to work.

Comment: I felt as if your first passage contradicts the second; I am having hard time understanding the answer ; likely I lack some background knowledge to understand it and yet you might want to rephrase it or at least removing the quotes.

Comment: @timesharer: Yes, it might be useful to learn about the concept of third-party cookies and tracking first. And maybe about the concept of embedding third-party contents ("like" buttons, trackers) into a site. See for example [How do Third-Party “tracking cookies” work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897472/how-do-third-party-tracking-cookies-work).

Comment: I don't lack the fundamental knowledge about cookies, I know they are strings of data stored in the browser to know a users preferences (such as a shopping cart), login sessions, etc. I have read several times in my life that `Other websites CAN access the cookies from another website` but you say that it's incorrect... I count on your word many years now but just surprised.

Comment: @timesharer: *"Other websites CAN access the cookies from another website"* -. could you give me a source for this, where this does not mean to include a third-party script into the local origin (explicitly or by security issues like XSS)? And even with some explicitly given access only some cookie can be read, i.e. no httponly cookies. Cookies have something similar to same origin policy to prevent cross-site access.

Comment: The last time I read such a statement was a few days ago in the Hebrew Wikipedia article עוגייה (אינטרנט) which states:

Comment: `לעיתים, גם אתרים שאינם האתר שיצר את העוגיה יכולים להשתמש בה.` Which means like "often, also websites which not have created the cookie can use it"

Comment: I have also heard a similar statement from various webmasters and programmers through the years, talking about how cookies can expose data on a user based on reading cookies his browser got from other websites.

Comment: @timesharer: As I said, cookies use a variation of the same site policy. Depending on the settings on the cookie www.example.com might read a cookie set by example.com. Also the port can differ. But not the "public domain", i.e. access between example.com and facebook.com is not possible. So there is some very limited cross-site sharing, limited to what is considered managed by the same entity.

Comment: @timesharer: As for the statement on Hebrew Wikipedia: I have not enough context for this statement to understand if it means this limited sharing, something else or if it is plain wrong (yes, this happens also sometimes with Wikipedia)

Comment: yes, I know very well about mistakes in Wikipedia; but anyway, I think I now got the point you tried to make --- the websites themselves generally don't share cookie data (unless they are under the same website network) but website companies might share cookie data (most likely automatically) between themselves, based on legal agreements ... Is that correct?

Comment: @timesharer: I've never heard of website companies having agreement to share cookie data. And __since cookie based tracking works without such sharing it would not even be needed__. Also, cookie sharing alone would not even allow tracking, also the association with a specific user (like email) had to be shared too to allow tracking over multiple sites.